# Scanning Values Until Getting a Significant Character in C

Tags: c

For my homework, I am trying to code a calculator which can also calculate average of taken numbers. I don't want to ask for number of numbers because our teacher don't want it in that way. So I thought of scanning values until the user presses "p". But as you would guess, the numbers are float and "p" is a character. What I want to do is assigning the value scanned to both of them if it is possible. I tried different ways, played with the codes but it isn't working properly. So I am seeking your advice.

It prints a value when p is inputted as like 3rd, 5th, 7th (oddth) number (sometimes right, sometimes wrong but I can fix it if I figure this out). But it doesn't print a value in other occasions and expects infinite inputs from the user.

This is the code I have written for this. `scanf("%f %c", &number1, &pause);` command is where I want to know about, actually.

```
#include<stdio.h>

float number1, number2, i, result;
char pause;

int main() {
  scanf("%f", &number1);
  i = 0;
  while (pause != 'p') {
    number2 = number1 + number2;
    scanf("%f %c", &number1, &pause);
    i++;
  }
  result = number2 / (i - 1);
  printf("%f", result);
}
```

Comment: __1:__ Please [edit] your question and  show an example of input and expected output. __2:__ hint: don't use `scanf` but use  `fgets` and scan the string yourself using `sscanf`. __3:__ other hint: format your code properly, for example like the samples in your beginner's C text book.

Comment: `scanf` returns a value that is useful: the number of items converted. So `while (scanf("%f", &n) == 1) ...` will handle float input until invalid input is encountered or the input stream runs out.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use double not floats if there is no specific reason to do so (like using uC without double FPU).
2. You do not initialize the variables
3. Always check the result of the I/O operation.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () 
{
    double number1= 0, number2 = 0, i = 0, result = 0;   
    char pause = 0;
    char line[128];

    while (pause != 'p')
    {    
        if(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin))
        {
            if(sscanf(line, "%lf %c",&number1, &pause) != 2)
            {
                printf("Wrong input - try again\n");
                pause = 0;
                continue;
            } 
            number2 = number1 + number2;
           i++; 
        }
        else
        {
            // do something with I/O error
        }
    } 
    result = number2 / (i-1);
    printf("%lf",result); 
}
```

You can play with it yourself : https://onlinegdb.com/Hy3y94-3r

Comment: Thank you for your help but some of the things in this proggram are beyond my knowledge, I am a newbie so I didn't understand how does it works. Also, when I tried to run your program, it says wrong input every time i put in a number.     
Thank you for the website by the way.

Comment: you need tenter number and the char every time

Answer (score 1):

I noticed 3 problems with your code.

First I would advise you to use meaningful variables names. `number1`, `number2`, etc. and the `i` which represents the number of inputs given can be an `int` instead of a `float`.

Secondly, you lack of printing to the user what's going on in your program; it's better to have messages like "enter your number, do you wanna stop? the result is...etc".

Lastly, having two inputs in one line of code can make it hard to debug, knowing that reading strings and characters in C is already hard for beginners. For example, %c does not skip whitespace before converting a character and can get newline character from the previous data entry.

Here is my fix: I changed some variables' names, printed some messages and read the two inputs in two different lines with adding `scanf(" %c")` with the space to avoid that problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>

float sum, temp, result;  
int nb;
char pause;

int main () {

        pause='a';
        while (pause != 'p'){

            printf("Enter your number: ");
            scanf("%f",&temp);
            sum+=temp;
            nb++;

            printf("type 'p' if you want to stop: ");
            scanf(" %c",&pause);
        }    

        result = sum / nb;
        printf("the average is : %f",result); 

}
```

I tested it, should work fine

Edit: after explaining that you don't want to ask the user each time, here is how the code should work (the case that the user don't input a `float` is not treated, and just take it as zero

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float sum, temp, result;  
int nb;
char input[50];

int main () {

        sum=0;
        nb=0;
        printf("Enter your numbers, then type 'p' to stop\n");

        do{
            printf("Enter your next number: ");
            scanf("%s", input);

            if(strcmp(input,"p")!=0)
            {
                float temp= atof(input);
                sum+=temp;
                nb++;
            }

        }while(strcmp(input,"p")!=0);    

        if(nb!=0)
        result = sum / nb;

        printf("\nThe average is : %f",result); 

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I wrote informative print commands actually but I didn't put them here just not to make it look too crowded. And to talk about the code you have written, it asks the user if he/she finished putting values every single time. And if user types p in the wrong time, it prints a wrong answer. This came into my mind too but as I said, I want the program to keep scanning float values until user inputs 'p', without asking the user "are you done?".

Comment: @Ivan86 yeah do-while is differently better, I tried to keep the code as close to his and thought maybe he didn't learn about do-while yet

Comment: @pipebomb434 I think in this case you will have to read a string from the user then check if it's "p" using strcmp, and if it does not convert it to float